# Chrome version 90 - input type time

Tags: google-chrome, input

Since yesterday version (version 90.0.4430.72 ) I can't enter a time with keyboard. I have to click on the icon clock and select hours and minutes from the dropdown which is not very easy. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a Chrome bug.  I am having the same issue so I opened a bug report with Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1199352:

> **Issue 1199352: Focusing `<input type="time">` does not highlight hours**
>
> UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36
>
> Steps to reproduce the problem:
> 1.Click on an input of type "time"
>
> What is the expected behavior?
> The input should focus and highlight the hours
>
> What went wrong?
> The input focuses but the hours text is not highlighted
>
> Did this work before? Yes 89.0.4389.114

It was subsequently [confirmed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1199352#c5):

> Able to reproduce the issue on windows 10, Linux and Mac 10.11.2 using chrome version 90.0.4430.72.Input focuses but the hours text is not highlighted
> Please find the bisect information as below.

It was subsequently [fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1199352#c40) and merged into Chrome 90 and 91

> The main issue has been fixed in M90 and M91, thanks everyone for the help.